# How do I allow users to customize e commerce store themes in wyswg using php html css js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am doing a school project of an online store with php & mysql.

I want anyone to use this program regardless of what they want to sell. So how can i allow them to customize the front-end without any knowledge of html & css.

I once thought of using html's "contenteditable" attribute but i couldn't come up with a way to save what the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make input boxes, so they can add their own items.

Comment: thanks buddy, so on every section of a page i would add an edit button and redirect them to a textbox ,, should i use file streams to write the html file or store the content i a database